Simplify Exam Writing Process With Macros
When writing using the exam document class in latex, I want to add parts (subparts and subsubparts). Currently, this must be done like so
\begin{questions}
\question Question 1 
\begin{parts}
\part[3] Part 1 (worth 3 marks)
\part[4] Part 2 (worth 4 marks)
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

Is there a way to simplify this so part so as to eliminate the need to have the \begin{} and \end{} commands, and also replace the \question and \part code with quicker \q and \p code (that could also be extended to simplify the commands for subparts and subsubparts).
My vision for the code with macros/commands is something like the following:
\q Question 1
\p[3] Part 1 (worth 3 marks)
\p[4] Part 2 (worth 4 marks)

Is there a way this can be achieved in Latex?
Cheers

Instead of defining additional shorter macros I would suggest to use an editor, that allows to define shortkeys.

You will need to put the text into arguments (braces) in order to tell the parser where the \part ends.

Supporting cabohah's idea this e.g. this editor allows you defining user-completion-commands: TexMaker

User
/Customize Completion


Though it's nonsense in this context, starting to write a command envokes autocompletion, e.g. the one I showed:

For a huge review of Latex Editors and IDEs have a look here: LaTeX Editors/IDEs

Here is a way to do it via macros, as you requested. Refactoring (examples in LaTeX) is the/a way to do that, while in this simple example the gain is questionable.

Some remarks on my code below:

next time please provide code, which will compile; here I'm just guessing about your preamble
as a consequence I didn't care about the leading numbers for the quesions (can certainly be switched-off)
\newcommand is what you are looking for
naming is critical (without digits etc.), though this way you'll be warned if a macro with the same name schould already exist (that's why you use \newcommand)
end each line tight by % to avoid spurious insertion of spaces
formatting of the "calls" is up to you; I used an indenting approach from structured programming
though you certainly could impose an even shorter syntax, I recommend to stay with LaTeX conventions (i.e. you'd ahve to account for nesting like \q[] suggests ...)


\documentclass[]{exam}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\qenv[2]{%   1: Q-number, 2: content
 \begin{questions}%
    \question Question #1%
    #2%
 \end{questions}}

\newcommand\penv[1]{%   1: content
    \begin{parts}%
        #1%
    \end{parts}}

\newcommand\prt[2]{%    1: part-number, 2: content
    \part[#1] #2}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 % ~~~ posted code ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{questions}
    \question Question 1 
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] Part 1 (worth 3 marks)
        \part[4] Part 2 (worth 4 marks)
    \end{parts}
 \end{questions}
 
 % ~~~ refactored ~~~~~~~~
    \qenv{2}{
%       hi world    % content during refactoring
        \penv{
            \part[3] Part 1 (worth 3 marks)
            \prt{5}{Part 55}
        }
    } 
 
\end{document}

